# Unable to Display GCM register Device id in Alert Box or toast in Android

Tags: android

```
if (!share_pref) {

            try {
                GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(CategoryPage.this);
                GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(CategoryPage.this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
            if (!regId.equals("")) {
                Log.i("GCM_STATUS", "Already Registered with Gcm");
            } else {
                GCMRegistrar.register(CategoryPage.this, Constants1.SENDER_ID);
            }
            Log.e("GCM", "ID----->"+regId);
```

i want to display My device id in Alert Box .i have written code for that But it does not work.While in LOG(console) I am Getting device id.please help me how to display device regId id in Alert Box so that i can see my device Id on UI

Answer (score 0):

you can not get registration id imediately after **GCMRegistrar.register(context, senderIds);** , So you have to do it in asynctask and reiterate untill you get it... try following code..

```
if (!share_pref) {
     registerInBackground();
 }
class GcmRegisterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
        GCMRegistrar.register(context, senderIds);

        regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(context);
        return regId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        if (result == null || result.length() == 0 || result.equals("")) {

            registerInBackground();

        } else {
             Log.i("regId=", result + " ==");
        }
    }

 }

    private void registerInBackground() {
    Log.e(TAG, "registerInBackground");
    GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
    new GcmRegisterTask().execute();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned ,you are getting the registration ID from GCM Server in Logs.

That means you are getting the Registration ID correctly from the GCM Server.

What do you mean by to get the device id in ALert Box?

Do you want to display the registration ID somewhere in your UI?

Or do you want to display it in the Notification you are receiving from GCM?

If you want to display in UI, create a text View and set registration ID as text on it.

Or if you want to display it in the Notifications you are receiving ,then you should read the value of registration id from shared preferences in onMessageReceived in GCM Intent services and append that value to text in Notification.

Comment: yes can u please help me I have tried But Unable to do this tell me ur mail id i ll send u code

Comment: write clearly what are you intending to do? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: actually i am to register device id am Able o Print in Log But i want to Print it On UI controls Like Alert Box I i write Toast code for display device id But not displaying But in console Log AM gettin device i d

Comment: Ok that means your code is correct. You tried with toast but you are not getting it on UI right, this is because you can update UI only from main thead ,trying posting toast to the UI thread using handler.It shall appear then.try!!

Comment: yes code is correct Basically am Printing regId But not Geting in toast or Alert